# How can I reset my game?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

My game is frozen (it glitched, not sure how). I really don't know how to reset the file. I barely ever get access to the Internet, so I don't really have the time to look it up.

Comment: If you saved in Lumiose city, go find internet access. This is caused by an early bug that was fixed in one of the first patches, downloading the patch will fix the error even if your save file is currently affected.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to do a softreset, just press and hold <kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>Start</kbd> / <kbd>Select</kbd>.

If you need to restart the game press <kbd>Up</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> simultaneously at the opening sequence.